# jQuery: call the action's form after calling preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below shows an error message when a field is not filled.

As you can see I'm calling preventDefault(), but...how to call the action associated to the form if the field has been filled??

```
$('input#save').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  if($('#field_1').val() == ''){

    $('#error_file').show();

  }
});
```

Comment: Consider using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input#save').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  if($('#field_1').val() == ''){

    $('#error_file').show();

  }
  else 
  {
     $('#my_form').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Alternately, `$(this).closest('form').submit();`

Comment: No need to traverse if he's already referencing `input#save` though. If he had selected `input.save` then I would definitely agree with the use of `closest()`

Comment: @Matt, a bit expensive..  since it is an `input` element inside a `form`, then  `this.form.submit()` will do ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is where you've placed `e.preventDefault()`. You only want to prevent default if the validation fails, so just move it inside the if condition.

```
$('input#save').click(function(e){
    if($('#field_1').val() == ''){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#error_file').show();
    }
});
```