# unable to call submit() after calling preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a form after clicking the submit button, so I'm preventing the form from automatically posting and refreshing the page with `preventDefault()`. After calling `preventDefault()`, I call another function to validate, like so:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    validate();

});
```

Here, `#submit` is the ID for the submit input element.

At the end of `validate()`, I try to call `submit()` on the form element `#homeForm`, but it doesn't seem to fire.

```
validate() {

....

console.log('test'); // this is firing

$('#homeForm').submit();
}
```

I used a few other Stack Overflow answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915637/7386637) to arrive at this solution, but I'm not really sure why it's not working. What could be preventing the `submit()` function from firing?

**Edit**: I've added a bit of what this form looks like in the HTML

```
<form id="homeForm">
....

    <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" action="javascript:void(0);">
</form>
```

Comment: What element has id `homeForm`? Is it a `<form>` element? If so, show it in your question. Are there any other event handlers bound to the `#homeForm` element?

Comment: I've added the form element along with the input submit inside of it. No other event handlers on #homeForm

Comment: I think you just need to set the action attribute appropriately

Comment: @kemika wow I totally didn't catch that the action attr was in the complete wrong place. would be glad to mark it correct if you answered once I got home

Comment: you should not put `$('#homeForm').submit();` inside validation function , rather you should call after the validation function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form `action` attribute should belong to the `<form>` element and should (probably) refer to a url

Answer (score 0):

The simpler method is to have the submit button call `validate()` function, then at validate function, if all is validated fine, then submit the form using `$('#homeForm').submit()`. This way you will never use `preventDefault` which I feel is the cause for whatever the reason.

**Edit:** Of course, then your button type should not be 'submit' for this.

Comment: So add an onClick to the submit input?

Comment: Change submit to button with onclick?

Comment: yes. would be better if you change it to a button tag with type='button'. Else I believe it would submit the form by default which would skip validate(). Else you may have the input type='button' and try from there.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I will give this a try and let you know what happens